# Python: pysftp exception handling

Tags: python, pysftp

I am using pysftp with Python 3.7 to setup an SFTP client script.

My code (simplified and minimal):

```
import pysftp
import sys

# Variables
destination_dir = 'BOGUS_DIR'
server = 'myserver.mydomain.com'
user = 'my_user'
key = 'my_key'
port = 22

# cnopts
mycnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
mycnopts.log = True
mycnopts.compression = True
mycnopts.ciphers = None
mycnopts.hostkeys = None

try:
    with pysftp.Connection(server, username=user, private_key=key, port=port, cnopts=mycnopts) as sftp:
        try:
            with sftp.cd(destination_dir):
                print("OK cd worked")
        except:
            print("NOT OK cd failed")
            e = sys.exc_info()
            print("Exception: {0}".format(e))

        if sftp.isdir(destination_dir):
            print("OK isdir")
        else:
            print("NOT OK isdir")

except:
    print("Connection failure.")
    e = sys.exc_info()
    print("Exception: {0}".format(e))
```

The output is: **OK cd worked**

But I know for a fact that `BOGUS_DIR` does **not** exist.  It is like pysftp does not raise the exception  on `cd()`, or I am catching it wrong (hence my python code is not properly done).

Same for `isdir()`, whatever I put as parameter, it always returns `True` even if the directory does not exist.

If I change my connection parameters for something wrong, I do catch the connection failure exception.

Is pyftp processing exceptions wrong, or is my code at fault here?  Should I not trust pysftp and use Paramiko directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, I think.

`sftp.cd()` does not raise an exception if the directory does not exist.  Only operations on the bad directory do.  So if I modify my code like this:

```
....
    try:
        with sftp.cd(destination_dir):
            sftp.listdir()
            print("OK ce worked")
    except:
        print("NOT OK cd failed")
        e = sys.exc_info()
        print("Exception: {0}".format(e))  

....
```

This way I get an exception since `sftp.listdir()` cannot work with an inexistent directory.

Almost like `sftp.cd` does not do anything other than set the value of the current directory, without actually doing anything with it.

Comment: have you run to any situation where there is no read or list permission?

Comment: Yes, in that case, the code works since a specific exception is raised, indicating the permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

If directory is not exist you getting an error from remote shell where you trying to run the command. In this code you trying to catch the exception that can be raised only by `sftp`. Maybe, you should check the status code that should be returned by `sftp` module after each executed shell command

Comment: he?  pysftp is a library that does SFTP py using Paramiko.  Paramiko is not a shell command implementation, it is a complete SSH client.  Unless of course I missunderstood completly!

Comment: Sorry, my fault. When  I connect to remote server by SFTP (or SHH) my default current directory is a `home`. You sure that directory is not exist in your default location after connection?

Comment: I put something so crazy that I am sure it does not exist, like `awhFa4F3wafbHhw`.

Comment: Try to `chdir` instead `cd`